# Cannot convert string[] to string

Tags: c#, arrays

I had error "cannot convert string[] to string"

```
string[] digitsArray = {dd, pp, ff, cc};
```

As digitsArray  array of arrays and all "dd, pp, ff, cc" are arrays have string values

Comment: No, it isn't. `string[]` represents a 1-dimensional array. `string[][]` represents a 2-dimensional array, or array of arrays.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you want

```
string[][] digitsArray = {dd, pp, ff, cc};
```

Answer (score 1):

As if you haven't been given enough solutions already - a LINQ version:

```
var digitsArray = new[]{dd, pp, ff, cc}.SelectMany(foo=>foo).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one-dimensional array - you can use [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) and [Enumerable.ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx):

```
string[] digitsArray = dd.Concat(pp).Concat(ff).Concat(cc).ToArray();
```